# dbgrid looping to update data not working

Tags: oracle11g, delphi-7

so I have a DBGRID that has this infos :

[image]

I wanted to edit values inside that DBGRID. I provide a button with codes :

```
    var ptlok, idp, tgl, after, kode, jlh, sql, sqla:string;
begin
  while not dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Eof do 
  begin
    ptlok:=dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[0].AsString;
    tgl:=dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[1].AsString;
    after  := stringreplace(tgl, '/', '-', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    kode:=dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[2].AsString;
    jlh:=dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[3].AsString;
    idp:=dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[4].AsString;
    sql:='update kasir_opname_detail set kode='+quotedstr(kode)+', 
      jumlah='+quotedstr(jlh)+' where ptlokasi='+quotedstr(ptlok)+' and 
      tanggal=to_date('+quotedstr(after)+','+quotedstr('dd-mm-yyyy')+')'+' and 
      idpay='+quotedstr(idp)+'';
    sqla:=sql;

    zquery13.close;
    zquery13.sql.clear;
    zquery13.sql.add(sqla);
    zquery13.execsql;
    dbgrid2.DataSource.dataset.Next;
    showmessage(sqla);
    //end;
    label19.Caption:=sqla;
  end;
  showmessage('Data Berhasil Disimpan!');
end;
```

However the data aren't saved as expected. it will only read last line of DBGRID then updates all data with values from last line of DBGRID.
is there something wrong with the code?
(prev it works with different dbgrid)
I am using delphi 7 and oracle as database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you are on the last line in the dbgrid when you click the button ? I guess you need to do `dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.First;` before you start your loop

Comment: @GuidoG where should I add this line? I tried put it before dbgrid2.datasource.dataset.next but it's not working. it saved 2nd row values to every row.

Comment: it's solved. my update codes is wrong. I should have put another condition in where clause. thanks @GuidoG

Comment: you still need to do `dbgrid2.datasource.dataset.First;` and you should do it before the `while not dbgrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Eof do`